# Change encoding from Azure logic app http get

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm not an expect with azure logic app but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

I have created an azure logic app HTTP GET retrieving the following file: http://www.msss.gouv.qc.ca/professionnels/statistiques/documents/urgences/Releve_horaire_urgences_7jours.csv.

This file is in French and contains some specific characters that the logic app does not recognize and output as "?". Do you know how I can change the source encoding so that the HTTP GET output keeps the special characters?

Thank you
David

Comment: Take a look here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2018/02/27/support-non-utf-payloads-in-logic-app-with-a-conversion-azure-function/

Answer (score 0):

As already told by Abhinav in the comments. Follow the blog by David burg which discuss about this.

**https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2018/02/27/support-non-utf-payloads-in-logic-app-with-a-conversion-azure-function/**

Sample of Function from the blog :

```html
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConvertEncoding
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<object> Run([HttpTrigger(WebHookType = "genericJson")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!");
 
            Encoding inputEncoding = null;
 
            string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
 
            if (data == null || data.text == null || data.encodingInput == null || data.encodingOutput == null)
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
                {
                    error = "Please pass text/encodingOutput properties in the input Json object."
                });
            }
 
            try
            {
                string encodingInput = data.encodingInput;
                inputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(name: encodingInput);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
                {
                    error = "Input char set value '" + data.encodingInput + "' is not supported. Supported value are listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx."
                });
            }
 
            Encoding encodingOutput = null;
            try
            {
                string outputEncoding = data.encodingOutput;
                encodingOutput = Encoding.GetEncoding(outputEncoding);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
                {
                    error = "Output char set value '" + data.encodingOutput + "' is not supported. Supported value are listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx."
                });
            }
 
            string input = data.text;
            var outputBytes = Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding: inputEncoding, dstEncoding: encodingOutput, bytes: Convert.FromBase64String(input));
 
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(content: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                text = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes)
            }).ToString(), encoding: encodingOutput, mediaType: "application/json");
 
    return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DixitArora-MSFT and Abhinav. I saw this article before and created the function. I added a step calling this function in my logical app. The thing is that I don’t know how to specify that it is the body (cab file) of my http request to be processed by the function. It does not seem to say in the blog. The answer may be obvious for an azure expert but I’m not hehe. 

Thank you again